Unable to get dotnet information while trying to create project in C#
I am beginner in C#, and currently trying to build my first project using C#.
But the problem is, I got the error after clicking this button which triggered by Ctrl+Shift+P in VSCode.
> .NET: New Project

The error:

Command '.NET: New Project...' resulted in an error
Unable to get dotnet information to initialize template engine host

I checked I successfully downloaded .NET Install Tool, C# from Extensions. And also check to my dotnet version is 8.0.301.
Has anyone seen this error or know how to figure out this one?

Did you try from console window, without visual studio code? dotnet new console

Did you install the .NET runtime or the .NET SDK? (The former allows you to run .NET apps (without needing to include the runtime in the app); the latter allows the creation of .NET apps as well as running them: try running dotnet --list-sdks from the command line).

I got the same host engine unable error and I tried closing everything and restarting the entire Mac, turns out it did work perfectly. Most of us never shutdown our Macs so I guess it needs a reboot to work. Try restarting your entire Mac. That’s my solution. Worked for me

From my experience, this is caused by the wrong SDK version being referenced by .NET CLI commands. Microsoft Learn specifies the below:
The process for selecting an SDK version is dotnet searches for a global.json file iteratively reverse-navigating the the path upward from the current working directory.

path upward from the current working directory.
dotnet uses the SDK specified in the first global.json found.
dotnet uses the latest installed SDK if no global.json is found.

The process for selecting an SDK version
Since you are using vs code to trigger the new project using .NET CLI, make sure there is no global.json file being referenced from and iteratively reverse-navigating from your current working directory which could have a different dotnet sdk than the one you installed.

If you find it, simply change the version to the one you installed, or rather remove it to pick the latest installed version. You may try to change your working directory to the root folder and run the .net cli command from there. The image above is an example of the global.json.
